# Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool

Tags: solidity, remix

```
pragma solidity  0.8.10;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
contract creditcardassociate {
    uint private cccount = 0;
    function addcreditcardCounter() public{
        cccount += 1;
    }
    function getCount() public view returns (uint){
        return cccount;
    }
    string fullname =""; 
     function _outputassociatenumber () public view returns (string memory) {
       return fullname;
    }
    function _inputAssociatenumber (string memory _s) public {
        fullname= _s;
    }
    uint assoicatecc;//variable
    function _inputthinkccnumber (uint x) public{
        assoicatecc = x;
    }
    function _outputthinkccnumber () public view returns (uint){
        return assoicatecc;
    }
    function checkCreditcards () public view returns (string memory){
        if (assoicatecc = cccount) {
            return "yes";
        }
        else (assoicatecc != cccount); {
            return "no";
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool`

Comment: Heyy,
I know you are new to this.
Please try to ask questions by giving reference to your contract and explaining the problem

Answer (score 1):

Check out this line in your code:

```
        if (assoicatecc = cccount) {
```

That `if` statement contains an assignment expression (which returns the value assigned) instead of (what I assume you intended) an equality check `assoicatecc == cccount`. Since `ccount` is `uint256`, Solidity sees `if (uint256)` in terms of types here.